# Video on Chrome freezing

Tags: release-juno, google-chrome, videos

I'm using Chrome browser. During video play eg. Youtube, picture is freezing but sound still goes on until I move mouse. After this it's ok for few seconds then again video is freezing. I have Intel i7 with Intel HD 620 graphics.

I found workaround on reddit that you have to disable hardware acceleration in Chrome settings. But then I have screen tearing...

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue that no one has figured out a good solution for yet:
https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/121

Please use the thumbs up instead of adding comments that you also have the issue, because a lot of people  get notified for every comment added.

Comment: It seems you link to an unrelated PR on Github.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHewitt I've corrected the url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing media codecs?

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

Take a look at this link https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-things-to-do-after-installing-elementary-os you may find interesting options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wrote a few days back. It helped me with Intel HD4400 and Intel HD620:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17237/511

Answer (score 0):

After reading the issue (https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/121) it appears that the issue is related to the cursor disappearing.

Two options:

1. Disable hardware acceleration - videos on youtube will work, but high definition videos elsewhere may not (if your processor can't handle the software decoding).
2. Move the cursor constantly while watching youtube videos, or watch them full screen.

Note: I have also experienced this issue, and the above is true for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this, the **latest update** of Elementary OS has solved this issue!

[image: Elementary OS 5.0 Juno]

Answer (score -1):

You have to go to the [Chrome Settings -> System](http://chrome://settings/system) (`chrome://settings/system`) and disable hardware acceleration.

Comment: Then high definition videos in chrome don't play well.

Comment: I had this issue happen to me on my Thinkpad (i5 2520k, 8GiB RAM), and it was trying to use Hardware Acceleration for watching videos and other various HTML5 frames. After turning it off, my laptop was able to function properly and I haven't noticed any issue when watching videos in 1080p. 

I would guess that unless your computer can't handle it, you might have some issue with the drivers your elementary is using.

Comment: I have a 4k laptop, the issue is moving the mouse.